# Vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ implies Vector space over $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: linear-algebra

If $V$ is a finite dimensional space over $\mathbb{R}$ then is it also a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$.Also is the converse true ?

I was thinking of using Countability argument to disprove this ,but I can't seem to find any way. Please give some hint.

Comment: $\mathbb R^n$ is a finite-dimensional space over $\mathbb R$, but what would happen if you multiply an element of $\mathbb R^n$ by a scalar from $\mathbb C$?

Comment: Oh I see,but how do I deal with the converse?

Comment: A vector space over $\mathbb C$ has twice the dimension when it's over $\mathbb R$

Comment: Is $\Bbb R$ a vector space over $\Bbb C$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any vector space over $\mathbb C$ is automatically a vector space over $\mathbb R$, since multiplication by scalars is well defined.

Moreover, if $v_1,..., v_n$ is a basis of $V$ over $\mathbb C$ then $v_1,..,v_n, iv_1,.., iv_n$ is a basis of $V$ over $\mathbb R$.

This tells you not only that for a vector space over $\mathbb R$ the scalar multiplication to make it a vector space over $\mathbb C$ is not typically defined, but more, for a vector space of ODD dimension, we **cannot** even extend the scalar multiplication to make it a vector space over $\mathbb C$.